# How to move to another View using a button in ASP MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to access to another page(View) by click a button. I try to write that in HTML code of my View using  but it didn't work.

Shall I do it in Controller ? if yes how ? adding that I want to restrict the access only to the registred members.

this is what I tried :

```
<p><a href="~/Views/Voitures/Create.cshtml" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sell your Car &raquo;</a></p>
```

Comment: Take a look at the [HTML Actionlink helper](http://w3schools.bootcss.com/aspnet/mvc_htmlhelpers.html).

Comment: Direct `*.cshtml` href will not work in MVC, It will be `<a href="/Voitures/Create">Sell your Car &raquo;</a>`

Comment: yes it works ! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<a href="/Voitures/Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sell your Car &raquo;</a>
```

or

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create","Voitures")" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sell your Car &raquo;</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If using a button is a alternative, you can also use this (though the suggestion provided by Ubiquitous Developers is also good):

Method 1

**View**

```
<form method="POST">
 <input type="submit" name="sellCar" value="Sell your car" />
</form>
```

**MVC Controller**

```
public ActionResult Overview(string sellCar) {

   if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sellCar))
      return RedirectToAction("SellYourCar");   

   return View();
}

public ActionResult SellYourCar() {
   return View();
}
```

Method 2

**View**

```
@model CarMarketplace.Models.FormContent
<form method="POST">
 <input type="submit" asp-for="Continue" value="Sell your car" />
</form>
```

**MVC Controller**

```
public ActionResult Overview(FormContent content) {

   if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content.Continue))
      return RedirectToAction("SellYourCar");   

   return View();
}

public ActionResult SellYourCar() {
   return View();
}
```

**Model**

```
public class FormContent {
  public string Continue { get; set; }
}
```